# How to write css for each page in rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make different layouts for different pages in my rails application but if i am creating a different file in assets folder for a particular page then it is taking some values from different page and some from different that file. I am getting mad on this. I ve made a different layout file for that and include this `layout'home'` in each controller( home for home page).
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer. Actually its not a good practice unless and until you want a different a page in your web application which has totally different views from other pages. All you need to do is as follows:

Suppose i want a total different layout for console page. So here are the steps

1. Create a layout `console.html.erb` in layouts folder.
2. Change this line `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>` to 
   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "console_layout", :media => "all" %>`.
3. Also change the `javascript_include_tag` line if you want to include a different       javascript.
4. Go to `assets/stylesheets`.
5. Create a file `console_layout.css.scss` in that folder and include any stylesheets if you   want to add for that particular page. Suppose i want to include the `bootstrap_and_overrides.less` file for this console page. Write like this
6. `/*
   *= require 'bootstrap_and_overrides'
   *= require 'console'
   */`
7. In the end remove `self_tree .` from the application.css.

Doing this means you are actually creating a different layout, a different style sheet for that console page. After creating this it will never ever take values from other stylesheets.
I would like to mention do this only if you need to create a page which has total different style and has nothing to do with the other page's styling.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

To create new css you must created a view or a controller.

I do not recommend creating separate files. I recommend you use the rails generator.

For example, if you want create a new view you must write:

```
rails generate controller credit_cards open debit credit close
```

This generate a file controller `credit_cards`, the views `debit credit` and `close`, assets `credit_cards.scss` and javascript `credit_cards.js.coffee`,

**Your `credit_cards.scss` file prevail over the other scss files for view `credit_cards/debit`, `credit_cards/credit` and `credit_cards/close`.**

you must manually create the layouts and add it to your controller or your actions inside controller with:

```
layout "name_layout"
```

or in each action:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :layout => 'name_layout' }
 end
```

To specific .carousel:

in your `view.html.erb`

```
<div class="credit_card">
  <div class="carousel">
   content here..........
  </div>
</div>
```

in your `file.scss`

```
.credit_card > .carousel { margin-bottom:0px; width: 10px;}
```

Best regards!

Comment: yeah i used rails generator for each n every page. But the thing is my home.css.scss is taking some values from gallery.css.scss. Inspite of having different layouts for each n every page.

Comment: for example i ve this 
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
} for my home page. Now for my gallery page i want this piece of css but with some changes like margin-top: 20px; But it is not working like that. It is taking the values of home page only.

Comment: you can create a new div that covers the `carousel` class and give style carousel specific only to that div. I have edited my response

Comment: i did that too.. But whenever i am creating a new page and copying the same but with different changes it is taking the values from different css file. Is it the only solution that we shud create a new div. I m wondering that can we make some changes in the layout file. i ve copied the same application.html.erb into all gallery and home layout file. Is it correct.?

Comment: You can add the div to views or to layouts. The effect is the same!

Comment: But should i do this all the time?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that there is a line like:

> *= require_self

in your `application.css` file present inside `assets/stylesheets`.

These lines are used by sprockets for asset pipe lining. You could avoid requiring all of the files and explicitly declaring the ones which you need.

Similarly in your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, you have this line.

> 'all' %>

I would rather not touch this, but instead would declare the particular stylesheet for a particular view within it.

Read more on asset pipeline and how it is helpful in speeding up your app. Its a great read.

Side note: I am not really sure if you would want different styles for same class. It feels that you are trying to do things which would be difficult to maintain in the long run. I would rather have added a new class. And instead of using the existing class, used the new one. The naming convention would have been related to the controller name or the view name.

Comment: hey thanks a lot. But ive already found one solution for this. I didnt update the answer. I ll surely do. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused. Each controllers generated css file (as well as all others) will be included with every request if `*= require_tree .` is in `application.css` manifest file. I recommend having each of your layout files possibly having a unique id on div, possibly the controllers name. Then, in each controllers sass file, use the id and you will no longer have conflicting css.

Example

```
div#homeController.container
  color:red
```